# Javascript- Splitting an array I'm looping through without changing the loop array

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, loops, reference

```
var arrayLength = splitData.length;

for(var i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){
  if(splitData[i]== '----------------\r\n#NOTES:\r\n'){
    console.log("Notes section found...");
    noteSection = true;
  }

  else if(i==1){
    var tempArray = splitData[i];
    var titleData = tempArray;
    titleBox = titleData.split("\r\n");
    for(var i=0; i<titleBox.length; i++){
      var bpmBox = titleBox[i];
      if(bpmBox.indexOf("BPMS") >= 0){
        var bpmBoxSplit = bpmBox.split("=");
        BPM = parseInt(bpmBoxSplit[1]);
        console.log("BPM found: " + BPM);
      }
    }
  }
```

So I have an array and a for loop that iterates through the array, searching for a particular string:

```
'----------------\r\n#NOTES:\r\n'
```

But for some reason, my else if statement has some code in it that's altering arrayLength, and is causing my loop to skip straight over the string I need.

```
var titleData = splitData[i];
titleBox = titleData.split("\r\n");
```

This bit of code is messing things up and I don't really understand why or how to work around it. I assume when I do titleData.split("\r\n") that it is messing with arrayLength, since they are both referencing the same array. But I, again, don't fully understand why this would happen or know how to prevent it.

Basically, I need to do work with the very same array that I'm currently looping through, without altering or changing the original. I figured making a new variable would be good enough to accomplish this, but I guess not. Because whatever I do to one variable seems to affect the other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because you are using the same counter variable name, `i`, in both for loops, use a different counter variable name in one of the loops. Or define them with `let` instead of `var` to make them block scoped though I still would use different names to prevent confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nested for loops, which is OK, but you can't use the same variable i for both of them. In the inner loop, you are redefining the i variable of the outer loop, which of course messes up the order of the outer loop.

The solution is simple: use a different variable name in the inner loop, for example i2 oder ii.